Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at scripts-EEEIPNC3.js:1:1) when angular app deployment
I developed an angular application (Angular version 17). After deployment if i open the application. it is showing following error
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.Understand this errorAI
main-PI7SWQGV.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.Understand this errorAI
scripts-EEEIPNC3.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at scripts-EEEIPNC3.js:1:1)
Error
node express server is used and tried iis server also, getting same error. Please refer my angular.json bellow and help me to come out of this
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "qadashboardfe": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/qadashboardfe",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "aot": true,
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            },
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
                "highcharts"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "qadashboardfe:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "qadashboardfe:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "qadashboardfe:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "d65730db-8bc1-4d78-aaef-715dc5dc12b9"
  }
}

Build command used
 ng build --configuration production --output-path    dist/qedashboardfe --base-href /qedashboardfe/


The server that is serving your application needs to be configured to serve the correct mime type. This is for another library, but the issue is the same as yours:
https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/troubleshooting#:~:text=%22Failed%20to%20load%20module%20script:%20Expected%20a%20JavaScript%20module%20script%20but%20the%20server%20responds%20with%20a%20MIME%20type%20of%20%22text/plain%22

this is almost always caused by HTML being returned by the server... often that is an error page.  Probably a 404, check your path to that script.
